# Lists in beamer taking more than one frame

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I am preparing some slides using beamer.

I have to write a list of examples of a certain mathematical structure that takes more space than allowed in a single frame.

How can I avoid that the numbering restarts anew in the second frame?

I tried what I would do in the "usual" documentclass namely specifying the initial numbering by

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item[7]
```

but that changes the style of the numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution defining another counter `currentenumi` to store the value of the last enumerated item in a given frame. Then on the next frame, the `enumi` counter can easily be set to the value of `currentenumi` to continue numbering.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{currentenumi}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item An item
        \item Another one
    \setcounter{currentenumi}{\theenumi}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setcounter{enumi}{\thecurrentenumi}
        \item Another item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use overlays:

```
\begin{frame}{Examples}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<only@-6> first
        \item<only@-6> second
        \item<only@-6> third
        \item<only@-6> fourth
        \item<only@-6> fifth
        \item<only@-6> sixth
        \item<only@7-> seventh
        \item<only@7-> eighth, etc.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Then items 1–6 appear one one overlay, and item 7 onward appear on another.  This way in article mode you only get one list.  You can add overlay specifications to make the items appear incrementally, on separate frames in handout mode, etc.