# Resuming enumerate in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I adapt the answer in [Resuming a list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list?answertab=active#tab-top) to `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{enumerate}
  Some text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item Three
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compilation produces an error (while there is no error with document class `article`):

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].
\labelenumi ->{
               \labelenumi }
l.11 \end{frame}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Using `enumitem` in `beamer` is hard; see for example the discussions in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31505/201628) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24371/201628). If your goal is only to resume the enumeration, I think the simplest solution is to avoid using `enumitem` and to use another counter instead, as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531803/201628).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Continuing enumerate Counters in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55000/5764)