# Resume nested enumerate lists in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate

In beamer, I want to create two nested enumerate lists and continue the numbers without starting from the beginning like so.

```
1. 
2. 
     3.
     4.   
5.
6.
```

My code is based on this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531803/153274.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{currentenumi}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Plan}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
        \item {\large Summary}
        \vskip1em
        \item {\large Research}
        \setcounter{currentenumi}{\theenumi}
        \vskip1em
        \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{\thecurrentenumi}
            \item {\large Introduction}
            \vskip1em
            \item {\large Research During PhD}
            \vskip1em
            \item {\large Research During PostDoc}
        \end{enumerate}
        \vskip1em
        \item {\large Conclusions}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried this solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55001/153274 and it did not work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to change the counter of a second level enumeration, you need `enumii` instead of `enumi`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{currentenumi}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Plan}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[square]
        \item {\large Summary}
        \vskip1em
        \item {\large Research}
        \setcounter{currentenumi}{\theenumi}
        \vskip1em
        \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumii}{\thecurrentenumi}
            \item {\large Introduction}
            \vskip1em
            \item {\large Research During PhD}
            \vskip1em
            \item {\large Research During PostDoc}
            \setcounter{currentenumi}{\theenumii}
        \end{enumerate}
        \vskip1em
        \setcounter{enumi}{\thecurrentenumi}
        \item {\large Conclusions}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]